# Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

I code my solidity contracts and I test in Remix Web IDE. When I test and I not get errors I copy to my project folder in my local machine. And all this errors appear in Visual Studio Code.

I can migrate and compile with truffle and use. Without errors.

Who know´s what happening??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a problem with the compiler in visual studio. What pragma version are you using in the contract and what compiler version are you using in visual studio?

Comment: 0.4.24 in bouth

Comment: I think you have the 0.5.0 somewhere and having compatibility issues with older contracts like [explained here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#interoperability-with-older-contracts). Try changing the pragma to 0.5.0 and see if it persists.  Read more about [memory](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=memory#storage-memory-and-the-stack) also. If you still can't solve it consider uploading the contract so we can help you better.

Comment: The extension that I download was compiling the code in the 0.5 version